Re-create reaction and context menu in SwiftUI
In SwiftUI, it's super easy to make the menu that drops below a selected view (in the image the one with Reply, Add Sticker, etc). You just do .contextMenu { views } on your view.
Doing the emoji popup that shows above the selected view seems to be much more difficult. Is there some hidden incantation in SwiftUI that makes this easy? Or does it require a large solution that doesn't use contextMenu at all? Anybody done this?


This post might help: How to implement context menu with custom view in preview param that can interact in SwiftUI?

OMG That totally worked! You're my hero. And how the heck would I have discovered 'matchedGeometryEffect'? Anyway thank you so much! If you make an answer I'll mark it, if you want...

Pleased to hear you've found a solution. You're welcome to upvote the other answer if it helped (it was my answer), no need to duplicate here. Re. matchedGeometryEffect, see also the comment to this answer.
